# Почему в TypeScript рекомендуют именовать интерфейсы без префикса "i"?

Tags: typescript

В конвенции [написано](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/styleguide/styleguide.md#interface):

> Don't prefix with I

В [соглашениях](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces) к Angular так же написано, что префикс лучше не использовать мотивируя это тем, что не нужно как-то особенно выделять интерфейс.

Не понимаю, что в этом плохого? Например, почему не может быть абстрактного класса Car и интерфейса ICar, что бы дать выбор по какому пути расширять класс.

Если не использовать приставку, то тогда нужно именовать класс как CarBase => шило на мыло.

Comment: там же следующей строкой указана причина: _Reason: Unconventional. lib.d.ts defines important interfaces without an I (e.g. Window, Document etc)._

Comment: @Grundy виде. Ну... такой себе аргумент. В том же C# одно время рекомендовали при реализации своих исключений наследоваться не от Exception, а от спец. класса производного от Exception. Ну в итоге все забили на это, так как сами майки там у себя все напутали.

Comment: Если тебе не нравится причина можешь Issue там завести :-) но причина почему они не рекомендуют указана в том документе. При этом никто не запрещает добавлять этот префикс.

Comment: Ну ангулярская мотивация мне тоже малость не понятна. Они ссылаются на другое

Comment: Стоит добавить ссылку на рекомендации ангуляра, так же как на style guide по typescript

Comment: Добавил.........

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/121. Но если коротко - то потому что разработчики TS так захотели. В C++ было принято классы с `C` называть, в C# - интерфейсы с `I`, а в TS - все без префиксов.

Comment: и заодно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876947/confused-about-the-interface-and-class-coding-guidelines-for-typescript/41967120#41967120 - вдруг кто-то захочет перевести

Comment: это вкусовщина, тот же Боб Мартин в чистом коде тоже пишет что они не нужны.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ангуляровский стайл гайд создавали Мишко и папа Джон, эти люди в свое время писали на java/c#. Я не понимаю почему у людей появляются основания им не доверять. Я работал с людьми на проектах, которые приходили с С#, на вопрос почему вы используете `I` префикс - мне никто не отвечал. У TypeScript команды есть внутренний стайлгайд, который разработал Хейлсберг (думаю вы как С# дев знаете кто это :) ) и там также написано `Do not use "I" as a prefix for interface names.`

Comment: @iluxa1810 `Car + ICar` - это антипаттерн, означает что интерфейс в основном имеет 1 реализацию, а это значит что не должно быть интерфейса вовсе

Comment: @overthesanity, а `Car1 + Car2 + Car3 + ICar` уже не будет антипаттерном? :)

Comment: @Grundy не будет :) но тогда ты ничего не выигрываешь, если называешь `ICar` вместо `Car`, теоретически нет причин знать, что ссылка на тип `Car` относится к классу, а не к интерфейсу, и наоборот в TS

Comment: @overthesanity вы хотите сказать, что майки пропагандируют анти-паттерны в C#? У них, например, есть DbConnection и IDbConnection.

Comment: @iluxa1810 я ничего не говорю за C# вовсе, я не си-шарпер :)

Comment: @iluxa1810, кроме `DbConnection` у них есть еще как минимум `OleDbConnection` и `SqlConnection`